# How to allow restricted google apps domain AND personal gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-apps

I know that "X-GoogApps-Allowed-Domains" can help the user to block access to some Google accounts and services. But my problem is I have two Google Apps domains like domain1.com and domain2.com, I only want to the user only have access to domain1.com AND their own gmail account.

I tried to add gmail.com, google.com, mail.google.com to the value of "X-GoogApps-Allowed-Domains", but whatever I add to this header, I cannot have the access to my personal gmail account.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Hi... we need more information if we're to help you with this. How do you enter "gmail.com" and your domain at once? Do you have a sample of two of the combinations you tried? and what error do you receive? Where do you set that header? in an App Engine app?

Comment: You can add account, so you can switch between different gmail accounts.
If I add "domain1.com", I can access to user@domain1.com but neither user@domain2.com nor user@gmail.com.
If I add "domain1.com,gmail.com", the response is the same. But what I want to achieve is that I can access both of user@domain1.com and user@gmail.com.

Comment: you should be able to add both, separated with a comma. The value of the header is a list.

Comment: I tried to add "gmail.com" to the X-GoogApps-Allowed-Domains, but I cannot have the access to the user@gmail.com.
I wonder what should I put into that value so that I can have access to "domain1.com" and gmail.com, BUT NOT "domain2.com".

Sorry about the multiple editing comment, every time I click the Enter, the comment get pushed. And I am not very used to that.

Comment: Hey! Looking into basic documentation for the header, I don't think you can allow domains you do not own on it. So you will never be allowed to enable gmail on this. In any case, I think that your question should not be tagged "app engine", because this is google apps, not app engine...